# Values from NSString to NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsstring, nsmutablearray

I have a NSString with numbers e.g."1,3,6,7"
and a global NSMutableArray that is initialized elsewhere.

Now to get the numbers from the string to the Array I thought something like this would work:

```
[myMArray arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:([myString componentsSeparatedByString:@","])];
```

but it doesn't work. Can someone explain me why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method [arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html) returns a new, autoreleased, `NSArray` object. It looks like you're assuming it adds objects to an existing `NSMutableArray`. You should use the `addObjectsFromArray:(NSArray*)` method instead.

Answer (score 1):

In this method used to easy copy NSString to NSMutableArray:

```
NSMutableArray *array = array =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];   
NSString *datetime = @"(
        {
        content = "<p>Hallo lieber Falko,</p>\n<p>Ich bin auf der suche nach einem g\U00fcnstigen Urlaubsangebot, f\U00fcr eine Familie mit 3 ( 4;2;1) Kindern. Es soll auch nur f\U00fcr eine Woche sein. </p>\n<p>Vielen Dank f\U00fcr die mithilfe. </p>\n<p>Am besten Kreta, oder Kos. </p>\n<p>Mit freundlichen Gr\U00fc\U00dfen</p>\n";
        date = "2014-05-23 22:25:44";
        id = 2607;
        name = Elberskirch;
        parent = 0;
        url = "";
    }
)";

  array = [[datetime propertyList]mutableCopy];
NSLog(@"%@",array);
```